# Why IDEA import mockito last dependency version which contains old version subdependencies?

Tags: intellij-idea, mockito, maven-dependency

I am trying to get the `mockito-junit-jupiter 3.4.4` which according to the https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/3.4.4 contains `mockito-core 3.4.4` and `junit-jupiter-api 5.4.2`, but in IDEA in Maven Tab `mockito-junit-jupiter 3.4.4` contains `mockito-core 2.23.4` and `junit-jupiter-api 5.3.2` (screenshot). Why is this happening? I specify the dependency and version like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.mockito.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<junit.mockito.version>3.4.4</junit.mockito.version>
```

Wow, when I try to add full pom.xml I get It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. Full pom.xml:

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>some-service</artifactId>
<version>1.55.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>some-service</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.6.2</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.6.2</junit.platform.version>
    <junit.vintage.version>5.6.2</junit.vintage.version>
    <springfox.version>2.9.2</springfox.version>
    <junit.mockito.version>3.4.4</junit.mockito.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-helper</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>sb-redirect</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.vintage.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.200</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/integrationtests/**/*Test.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>2.5C</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/integrationtests/**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
                <failurePriority>5</failurePriority>
                <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <checkstyleRules>
                    <module name="Javadoc">
                        <property name="severity" value="ignore" />
                    </module>
                </checkstyleRules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <processDependencyManagement>false</processDependencyManagement>
                <rulesUri>${project.baseUri}/maven-version-rules.xml</rulesUri>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image]

Comment: You may use the "Show dependencies" button in Maven pane so that IntelliJ IDEA shows you the dependency diagram. Please provide the full pom.xml file

Comment: @OlgaKlisho, added

Comment: Is the issue reproduced with the latest IntelliJ IDEA version? (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/)

Comment: @OlgaKlisho, yes, 2020.2, IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-202.6397.94, built on July 27, 2020

Comment: Please file an issue at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ providing the sample project to reproduce the case. Thank you